# Qt MySQL -------- Cannot open include file: 'mysql.h':

Tags: mysql, sql, qt, qtsql

Im making a GUI application in Qt, it will be a front end to a database basically

however i haven't even got to the point of doing anything yet because my database connection just keeps failing (Well it doesn't actually compile so its not a DB connection issue)

Anyway my project wont even build because Qt gives the error:

```
 error: C1083: Cannot open include file: 'mysql.h': No such file or directory
```

which i dont particularly understand because in the class that uses the QtSQL stuff i have included:

```
#include <QtSql/QSqlDatabase>
#include <QtSql/QMYSQLDriver>
```

kind of banging my head against the desk now because it is my understanding from the documentation that these 2 includes are all you need, oh and this in my .pro

```
QT       += sql
```

am i missing something really obvious here?

cheers

Comment: Seems you're missing the mysql headers. Which OS do you use?

Comment: Windows 7 Professional, i have had a look in the Qt directory to see if i could find them, C:\Qt\Qt5.0.1\5.0.1\msvc2010\include\QtSql has all of the qsql_mysql.h etc but cant actually find mysql.h but surely thats been put somewhere when i installed Qt right?

Comment: No, they're not distributed together wit Qt. See Amartel's answer...

Comment: Yea just saw it, seems like its the solution iv been looking for cheers for help people!

Comment: But i think its a bit odd that this sort of thing isnt mentioned in the documentation at all ... -.-

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You actually don't need to include `QMYSQLDriver`. What you really need is to build mysql driver. Here is the [manual, which tells you how to do it](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/sql-driver.html#how-to-build-the-mysql-driver-for-mingw-users).

Comment: oh, when it wasnt included it compiled fine but when i tried to connect it outputted `MYSQL driver not loaded, QSqlDatabase: available drivers: QSQLITE` so basically this means that QSQL light is the only SQL driver that has been loaded automatically when Qt was installed, in that case building the driver will solve the issue right?

Comment: Yes. Qt is using plugin-based system to connect directly to different databases, using single frontend. All you need is to build concrete driver, put it in `plugins/sqldrivers` directory and be sure that it can reach all the dependencies (in your case it is mysql's client library).