# Error building QMYSQL Plugin for Qt on Windows

Tags: qt, qt5, mysql-connector

I recently re-installed Qt - and now I am having issues with my MySQL drivers for Qt.  I now get the error:

```
QSqlDatabase: QMYSQL driver not loaded
QSqlDatabase: available drivers: QSQLITE QODBC QODBC3 QPSQL QPSQL7
```

So I am trying to build the QMYSQL Driver.  So far I have...

1. Downloaded the MySQL Community installer by running [mysql-installer-web-community-8.0.18.0.msi](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/installer/)

   And installed the x86 version of the MySQL Connector C 6.11, which saved to C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Connector C 6.1

2. Opened a Developer Command Prompt for VS 2017 and ran:

   ```
       CD "C:\Qt\5.12.6\Src\qtbase\src\plugins\sqldrivers"
       qmake -- MYSQL_INCDIR="C:/Program Files (x86)/MySQL/MySQL Connector C 6.1/include" MYSQL_LIBDIR="C:/Program Files (x86)/MySQL/MySQL Connector C 6.1/lib"
   ```

   Which seems to work, as I get "yes" for MySQL:

   ```
       Running configuration tests...
       Checking for DB2 (IBM)... no
       Checking for InterBase... no
       Checking for MySQL... yes
       Checking for OCI (Oracle)... no
       Checking for ODBC... yes
       Checking for PostgreSQL... no
       Checking for SQLite (version 2)... no
       Checking for TDS (Sybase)... no
       Done running configuration tests.

       Configure summary:

       Qt Sql Drivers:
         DB2 (IBM) .............................. no
         InterBase .............................. no
         MySql .................................. yes
         OCI (Oracle) ........................... no
         ODBC ................................... yes
         PostgreSQL ............................. no
         SQLite2 ................................ no
         SQLite ................................. yes
           Using system provided SQLite ......... no
         TDS (Sybase) ........................... no

       Qt is now configured for building. Just run 'nmake'.
       Once everything is built, you must run 'nmake install'.
       Qt will be installed into 'C:\Qt\5.12.6\msvc2017_64'.

       Prior to reconfiguration, make sure you remove any leftovers from
       the previous build.
   ```

   **Note:** I have also tried installing the x64 version of MySQL Connector C 6.1 instead of x86, but when I run QMAKE then (after adjusting the INCDIR and LIBDIR parameters from qmake) It says 'no' for MySQL - which I *believe* means that I am correct to be trying to use the x86 version.

3. Then from the same CMD I run: `nmake sub-mysql` but I get the error:

   ```
   c:\qt\5.12.6\src\qtbase\src\plugins\sqldrivers\mysql\qsql_mysql_p.h(60): fatal error C1083: Cannot     open include file: 'mysql.h': No such file or directory
   main.cpp
   c:\qt\5.12.6\src\qtbase\src\plugins\sqldrivers\mysql\qsql_mysql_p.h(60): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'mysql.h': No such file or directory
   Generating Code...
   NMAKE : fatal error U1077: '"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.16.27023\bin\HostX86\x86\cl.EXE"' : return code '0x2'
   Stop.
   NMAKE : fatal error U1077: '"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.16.27023\bin\HostX86\x86\nmake.exe"' : return code '0x2'
   Stop.
   NMAKE : fatal error U1077: 'cd' : return code '0x2'
   Stop.
   ```

I've checked that 'mysql.h' DOES exist in 'C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Connector C 6.1\include'.
Is there something else I am missing or doing wrong?

**OS:** Windows 10
**Qt:** 5.12.6
**MySQL:** C Connector 6.11 x86
**Compiler:** MSVC 2017

Comment: Try using a path without spaces, for example copy it to the sqldrivers folder and rename it to "MySQLConnector"

Comment: @eyllanesc.  Now I get the error: <br> Qt5Sql.lib(Qt5Sql.dll) : fatal error LNK1112: module machine type 'x64' conflicts with target machine type 'x86'
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: '"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.16.27023\bin\HostX86\x86\link.EXE"' : return code '0x458'
Stop.
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: '"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.16.27023\bin\HostX86\x86\nmake.exe"' : return code '0x2'
Stop.
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: 'cd' : return code '0x2'
Stop.

Comment: as the error points you are trying to use x86 libraries (32 bits) in which you need to use x64 (64 bits)

Comment: But when I try the x64 C Connector libraries, I get 'No' when I run QMAKE for everything under the "running configuration tests...".  I only get 'yes' for MySQL when I use the x86.

Comment: Was the connector you used compiled with the same version of visual studio?

Comment: How can I check?  I used the msi installer from the oracle link above to install the connector.  https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/installer/  -which is what the Qt docs said to do.

Comment: Refer to [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15930894/qt-mysql-cannot-open-include-file-mysql-h)